# To define fields in items class in scrapy using a list

Tags: python, scrapy

#i want to create Field for my item class in scrapy im reading the list from a csv and then #converting it to a list but when i want to define fields in items class using init it gives me this error
#raise AttributeError(name)
#AttributeError: _values. Did you mean: 'values'?

#Anyways here is the code kindly help me fix this

```
fields = pd.read_csv('E:/pythonProject/webscrapping/postscrape/fields.csv')
fields = list(fields['0'])
fields.insert(0, 'Company')


class PostscrapeItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    def __init__(self):
        for f in fields:
            self.__dict__[f] = scrapy.Field()


i = PostscrapeItem()
print(i.Keys())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `scrapy.Item` class uses a non-standard meta class which makes overwriting `__init__` both impossible and unnecessary.

If your goal is to dynamically add fields to the item class it should work by setting the values of the `Item.fields` dictionary.

This example should show all that is needed:

```
fields = pd.read_csv('E:/pythonProject/webscrapping/postscrape/fields.csv')
fields = list(fields['0'])
fields.insert(0, 'Company')

class PostscrapeItem(scrapy.Item):
    
    @classmethod
    def load_fields(cls, fields):
        for f in fields:
            cls.fields[f] = scrapy.Item()

PostscrapeItem.load_fields(fields)
```

There is no need to create an instance.